# Вывод массива без запятой в конце

Tags: php

Переменная `$group` содержит массив, в котором нужно вывести последнюю строку без запятой. Делаю это так:

```
$group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';

$numItems = count($group);
$i=0;
foreach($group as $filter) {
   if(++$i === $numItems) 
       echo $group;
   else 
       echo $group',';       
}
```

не получается. Как правильно?

Comment: сравнение `$numItems-1` сделайте

Comment: С точки зрения производительности, которая, как правило, в данном случае не играет роли, это делается выводом первого значения, а потом всех последующих в цикле через запятую перед ними.

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = '';
foreach($group as $filter) {
   echo $i . $filter; 
   $i = ',';
}
```

Хотя ваш $group на массив мало похоже.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с объединением элементов массива в строку, на мой взгляд, наиболее удобен

```
echo join(',', $group);
```

Answer (score 1):

$group - строка, не массив. Проверьте, может ошиблись?

Подозреваю что $group - json объект, тогда его можно переделать в массив, а оттуда в строку:

```
$group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"}';

$array = json_decode($group, true);
$result = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = $key . ':' . $value;
}

$result = implode(',', $result);
```

На выходе получим:

> title:Title,artist:Artist,cover:img/1.png,file:./file/1.mp3

Comment: `$array = json_decode($group, true);
$result = [];foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = '"'.$key.'"' . ':' . '"'.$value.'"';
}

$result = implode(', ', $result);

echo '{'.$result. '},';` На выходе все с запятыми $result =$group. Нужна последняя строка без запятой

Comment: Ну так уберите запятую здесь '{'.$result. '},'; - тут в конце запятая для чего?

Вот вывод без запятой: http://ideone.com/9yrpIC

Answer (score 0):

Вы же получаете JSON. Возможно следует не передавать лишнюю запятую при отправке, либо просто удаляйте последний символ.

```
<?php
    $group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';
    $group_cut = substr($group, 0, -1);
    $arr = json_decode($group_cut, true);
    echo $arr['file'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще проще сделать. Просто заменить

> '},'

на

> '}'

```
$group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';
$group = str_replace('},','}',$group);
```

Answer (score 0):

В условие foreach надо добавить `as $key => $filter`и внутрь цикла добавить условие:

```
if ( $key != ($numItems - 1) ) { echo $group . ','; }
else { echo $group; }
```

И в определении массива убрать в конце запятую, то есть не:

```
$group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';
```

А так:

```
$group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"}';
```

Answer (score 0):

В принципе вам ответили, добавлю от себя способ с регуляркой, допустим, что у вас может быть не один массив, а несколько.

```
$group  =   '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';
$group  =   preg_replace('#\,{1}\z#', '', $group);
$group_ARR  =   json_decode($group, true);
var_dump($group);
print_r($group_ARR);
echo end($group_ARR);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $group = '{"title":"Title", "artist":"Artist", "cover":"img/1.png", "file":"./file/1.mp3"},';
  $group = substr($group, 0,-1);

  $array = json_decode($group);
  $result = [];

  foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
  }
  echo "<pre>", var_dump($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php

Потом:

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rtrim.php

Самое простое объяснение решения для вашей задачи.